# Find $E(X \mid Y=X+1/2)$ for $(X,Y)$ with given PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

suppose    f( x , y ) = x + y

$ 0 < x < 1$, $ 0  <y < 1 $.

Find $E(X \mid Y=X+\frac{1}{2})$

So far, what I got,

\begin{align}
f_{X \mid Y=X+\frac{1}{2}}
   & = \frac{\int_{x}^1 (x+y) \mathbb{1}\,dy}
            {\int_{0}^1 \int_{x}^1 (x+y) \mathbb{1}dy\,dx} \\
     & = \frac{x+   \frac{1}{2} -\frac{3x^2}{2}}{\int_{0}^1 (x+\frac{1}{2} -\frac{3x^2}{2}) \,dx} \\
   & = 2x+1-3x^2
\end{align}

$$
E(X \mid Y=X+\frac{1}{2}) = \int_{0}^1 xf_{X\mid Y=X+(1/2)}) \, dx
                = \int_{0}^1 (x)(2x+1-3x^2) \, dx
                = \left. \frac{2x^3}{3} +\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3x^4}{4} \right|_{0}^1 = \frac{5}{12}
$$

I'm still confused, this expectation and conditional distribution..
is it correct?

Comment: I don't think you conditional probability is correct. You should have $f_{X|Y} = \frac{f_{X,Y}}{f_{Y}}$ where $f_Y = \int_0^1 (x+y) dx = 1/2 + y$ then $E[X|Y = x + 1/2] = \int_0^{1/2} x \frac{(x + y)}{1/2 + y} dx$ with $y = x + 1/2$ in the integral. This is not a nice integral to take though... so hopefully I haven't made any mistakes.

Comment: Problem #20 [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Conditional.html) has the same joint density as your problem.

Comment: I believe so, but all instances of $y$ should be replaced. $E[X|Y = x + 1/2] = \int_0^{1/2} x \frac{(x + x + 1/2)}{1/2 + x+1/2} dx$

Comment: Both variables are bounded from $[0,1]$, therefore if we have the constraint that $y = x + 1/2$, this $\text{may}$ limit our bounds. Check: $y \ge 1/2$, otherwise $x \lt 0$ which violates its bound, so we know $x \gt 0$. For its upper bound we know $y \le 1$, therefore $x \le 1/2$.

Comment: Wrong title, now modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* $\mathsf E(X\mid y=x+1/2) = \mathsf E(X)\; [y-x=1/2]$ because lowercase $x,y$ are constant values, not random variables.  I'm assuming this is not actually what you want.

---

You have $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= (x+ y ) \;\big[x\in(0;1), y\in(0;1)\big]$.

So the support is the unit square.

I'm assuming you actually wish to evaluate: $\mathsf E\big(X \;\big\vert\; Y=X+\tfrac 1 2\big)$

That is the expectation of X when $(X,Y)=(X,X+\tfrac 12)$, which lies on the line-segement which runs from point $(0,\tfrac 12)$ to point $(\tfrac 1 2, 1)$. (AKA line $Y=X+\tfrac 1 2$ in the unit square.)

So: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E\big(X \;\big\vert\; Y=X+\tfrac 1 2\big) & = \int_0^{1/2} x f_{X\mid Y=X+1/2}(x)\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex] 
& =  \frac{\int_0^{1/2}x\,f_{X,Y}(x,x+\tfrac 1 2)\operatorname d x}{\int_0^{1/2}f_{X,Y}(z,z+\tfrac 1 2)\operatorname d z}
\\[1ex] 
& =  \frac{\int_0^{1/2} (2x^2+\tfrac x 2)\operatorname d x}{\int_0^{1/2}(2z+\tfrac 1 2)\operatorname d z}
\end{align}$$

Take it from here.

Comment: No, @alex, $z$ is just the variable of integration; an arbitrary token. Remember $\int_a^b g(x)\operatorname d x = \int_a^b g(z)\operatorname d z = \int_a^b g(\zeta)\operatorname d \zeta$.

Comment: and could you explain  why is it wrong? $ E[X|Y = x + 1/2] = \int_0^{1/2} x \frac{(x + x + 1/2)}{1/2 + x+1/2} dx $ in my point of view $f_{X|Y} = \frac{f_{X,Y}}{f_{Y}} $ this one also correct,

Comment: @alex Because you want $f_{X\mid Y=X+1/2}(x)$ not $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid x+1/2)$.  They are not the same thing.  The first is the conditional density of $X=x$ given that $(X,Y)$ lies on the line-segement, the second is the conditional density of $X=x$ given $Y=x+1/2$

Comment: Notice the distinction between $X$ and $x$.  One indicates the random variable, the other is just an arbitrary value.  A lot of confusion can be spared if you don't mix up the capitalisation.

Comment: @alex, yes it is.